# RStudio: list files doesn't work

Tags: rstudio

I want to list several tif-files in order to calculate a satallite based Index. 
I want to use these two orders:

setwd("C:/Satellitendaten/Rohdaten/BT")

list_files <- list.files(getwd(), pattern=".tif$", full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)

But as a result, there is nor running nor error. What might be a reason for no results? Are the orders correct?

Comment: I don't know why, but now it's running :X

Comment: Probably weren't in the right working directory so `getwd()` wasn't looking in the right space?